# Unity/Unreal Analog Stick Tracking

Tags: unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4

I was wondering how EA managed to implement a system in Skate 3 where you flick the right analog stick in various ways to do various tricks. Could it be done in Unreal Engine 4 or Unity where you track the stick's position and see where it goes?
Thanks!

Comment: Of course. UE and Unity3D have full support for input devices including console pads. You can program whatever you want on pads stick actions.

Comment: Thanks for that @JerrySwitalski. I had a look and saw all the mappings in UE but I dont know how to program my own stick actions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I can show on Unity3D example, as I dont know UE.

First you need to have pad attached to device, and have a method where you will print the number of each button/joystick axis. That is how you will know the id/number of each button or stick.

And to do this check this (this shows also how to program it) ([source](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/17669/setting-up-game-pad.html)).

> For gamepad buttons, set up new buttons in the input manager by using
>   "joystick button x" for the positive or negative buttons, where x =
>   the number of the button you want (starting with 0). The Type should
>   be "Key or Mouse Button". To use this in scripting, use
>   Input.GetButton("XX"), where "XX" is the Name of the entry from the
>   input manager.
>
> For gamepad analog sticks, set up new axes in the input manager by
>   using "Joystick Axis" for the Type. The left stick would need two
>   entries in the input manager, one horizontal (using the X axis), and
>   one vertical (using the Y axis). The right stick would need another
>   two, using the 3rd and 4th axes. To use these in scripting, using
>   Input.GetAxis("XX"), where "XX" is again the Name of the entry from
>   the input manager.

In your case you will want to check Joystick Axis as this is where the input from pads joystick will go.

Comment: I see, sorry I need to get more familiar with rules of this site. Thanks for info.